# BASH with YAD to display avg ping

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, ping, yad

I am new to bash and I am trying to ping a host and display the average ping times. I want to auto-update that value in a YAD window. 
I have it set in while loop, but the problem is that I have to close the window for the new value to repopulate.
Can yad achieve such dynamic update?

Thanks

```sh
#!/bin/bash

HOSTS="google.com"
COUNT=2

while true
do 
  echo $(yad --title="Latency Monitor" --text="$(ping -c $COUNT $HOSTS 2>&1 | tail -1| awk -F/ '{print $6}' )" --text-align=center --no-buttons --height=50 --width=300)
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old - but just adding

> --timeout 1

at the end of the yad switches will make it auto close after 1 second. So it becomes:

```
#!/bin/bash

HOSTS="google.com"
COUNT=2

while true
do 
  echo $(yad --title="Latency Monitor" --text="$(ping -c $COUNT $HOSTS 2>&1 | tail -1| awk -F/ '{print $6}' )" --text-align=center --no-buttons --height=50 --width=300 --timeout 1)
done
```